# I need help on my code javaScript This is my error scrollableView.currentPage is not a function?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-sdk

thi is my error code

```
ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1347,45778] /ui/common/TabGroupAndr.js:823
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:         scrollableView.currentPage(2);
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:                        ^
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: TypeError: scrollableView.currentPage is not a function
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at View.<anonymous> (/ui/common/ApplicationTabGroup_Andr.js:823:24)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at View.value (ti:/kroll.js:1604:27)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at View.value (ti:/kroll.js:1661:27)
```

Titaniun version 11.1.1

Comment: According to [the docs](https://titaniumsdk.com/api/titanium/ui/scrollableview.html) scrollableView.currentPage is a property not a function.  You could try `scrollableView.currentPage = 2;`

Comment: @James you could post this as an answer so it can be accepted. In older SDKs you had a setter `setCurrentPage(2)` and those were removed and transformed to normal properties. I'm sure it was `setCurrentPage(2)` before and it should be `currentPage = 2` now as you suggested

Comment: @miga I believe this to be a typo

Comment: @evolutionxbox "typo" in the sense of using a function instead of a property, then yes :) Again: it was a method in older SDK versions and now it is a simple property.